# Flot - how do I make my bars wider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

How can I make my bars in my bar diagram wider? I've tried all kinds of things such as setting the amount of ticks in the X axis, however nothing appears to be working as I expect.

Right now, the bars are really small.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Flot API](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/API.txt):

```
Customizing the data series
===========================

series: {
  lines, points, bars: {
    show: boolean
    lineWidth: number
    fill: boolean or number
    fillColor: null or color/gradient
  }

  points: {
    radius: number
    symbol: "circle" or function
  }

  bars: {
    barWidth: number
    align: "left" or "center"
    horizontal: boolean
  }
```

So, you should be able to set `barWidth` and be good to go.

Comment: However, now the bars overlap eachother in the X-axis. How can I fix that?